# Xamarin type or namespace name does not exist

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

When I build my iOS Xmarain Project 50 errors all about not existing namespaces.
Xamarin Android builds without a problem.

I didn't write this project, I just should look that it builds again.
After two days of lurking in the web to find a solution I ask you for help.

These are some of the 50 errors:

[image: Some of the 50 errors]

Comment: be sure all packages are installed.  Restart VS.  Clean your bin/obj folders.

Comment: Is there a possibility to find which packages are missing and where to find them?

Comment: the nuget package manager should be able to restore them all for you at once

Comment: Check if all the references are correct, the Linker isnt causing you problems and/or all the packages are imported ("using" clause) in their respective classes

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: No i couldn't resolve it yet.

Comment: Try updating your nuget packages to the latest version